# .htaccess too many redirects based on category slug

Tags: categories, htaccess

I moved my wordpress page up a directory and also changed a bunch of categories with new names. But when I try to set a 301 redirect via .htaccess and then access that category url, the browser errors with a "too many redirects" message.

```
Redirect 301 /category/cat-a/subcat-a/subsubcat-a/ https://example.com/category/newcat-a/newsubcat-a/

Redirect 301 /category/cat-b/subcat-b/ https://example.com/category/newcat-b/mynewsubcat-b/

... bunch more categories
```

the "category" slug stays the same in the new and old names.

I know there is a flag that makes a rule "final" but I'm not sure how I could make. Cause I also tried setting the flag afterwards like:

```
Redirect 301 /category/cat-a/subcat-a/subsubcat-a/ https://example.com/category/newcat-a/newsubcat-a/ [L]
```

I've tried this and many other variations but neither did work out in my favour.

Do I miss something. Im also not sure if there is a regex that solves that problem. Basically from what i've understand, this creates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from what you have posted why you are getting a redirect loop. We would need to see the rest of `.htaccess` file. However ....

You may be getting a conflict with existing mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) directives. `Redirect` is a mod_alias directive.

You no doubt have existing mod_rewrite directives with the WordPress front-controller. You have other redirects also. You should avoid mixing redirects from both modules since they may not execute in the order you expect (mod_rewrite always runs before mod_alias, despite the apparent order in the config file).

> I know there is a flag that makes a rule "final" but ...

That "flag" applies to mod_rewrite `RewriteRule`, not `Redirect` (mod_alias). By adding that flag to `Redirect` in this context it will simply be ignored.

You should change these mod_alias `Redirect` directives to mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` and include them **at the very top of your file**.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(category)/cat-a/subcat-a/subsubcat-a/(.*) /$1/newcat-a/newsubcat-a/$2 [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^(category)/cat-b/subcat-b/(.*) /$1/newcat-b/mynewsubcat-b/$2 [R=302,L]
```

This assumes that everything after the *categories* are copied onto the end of the target URL. eg. `.../subsubcat-a/foo/bar` becomes `.../newsubcat-a/foo/bar`.  (Which is what your original `Redirect` directives would have done.)

`$1` is a backreference to "category" (simply saves repetition) and `$2` is everything after the *category* string.

The `L` (`last`) flag is required here.

Test with 302 and only change to 301 when you are sure it's working OK - to avoid caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: That totaly solved my problem. Although I had a few new categories that had a name other than the wildcard (.*), but i fixed those with a mod_alias. Thanks!